# JavaScript history.back() conditionally

Tags: javascript, history

My website uses [asual address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) for implementing hash based URL.
On one of the pages I have placed a **back** link. I want the following behavior on click of this link.

```
$('#back_link').click(function(){
 If there is any entry in history it should do history.back()
 If no entry in history, load a default page.
})
```

Is it possible?

Note: I can do this in Firefox (window.location.hash are different before and after click of the link).
But this is not working in chrome.
I also tried using history.length but no success.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to the page by a link, you can check document.referrer and call history(-1) if it exists, but it will return empty if the user typed in the address, even if there is history. I don't think you can just get the url (or even existence) of unrelated browser history, as that would be a security problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.history.back(-1);return false;">Back</a>
```

[webkit / Chrome history.back(-1) onclick vs href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815838/webkit-chrome-history-back-1-onclick-vs-href-resolved)