# Creating a back link

Tags: javascript

I need to create a back link. I was adviced to use this to do it:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.history.back();">Back</a>
```

But it works only in IE and Mozilla, but not in Safari, Google Chrome and Opera. How to fix it?

Comment: Works on my Chrome, which is the latest (43.0.2357.124)

Comment: possible duplicate of [webkit / Chrome history.back(-1) onclick vs href](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815838/webkit-chrome-history-back-1-onclick-vs-href)

Comment: works in IE but doesn't in Chrome, Safari and Opera? well, I've never heard such in my life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're blocking the redirection using the `href`,

**replace**

```
<a href = "#" onclick="javascript:window.history.back();">Back</a>
```

**with**

```
<a onclick="window.history.back();">Back</a><--!javascript: is not required-->
```

**or**

Add a `return false;` to it.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.history.back();return false;">Back</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem of your code is the `onclick`'s value. The "protocol" `javascript:` is only required if you use JavaScript code within the `href` attribute. This signals your browser that the protocol of the link is not `http:` or `https:` but `javascript:`.

If you use the `onclick` attribute, the browser already knows that the value will be `JavaScript`, because all attributes like onclick, onfocus, onchange, ... require JavaScript as it's value.

**This will work:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.history.back(); return false;">Back</a>
```

Adding `return false;` as a second command will prevent the site from jumping to the top, but that's not required.